# Bootstrap validation not working despite including script and following docs

Tags: javascript, node.js, forms, mongoose

I can't get my form to validate despite having the script both on the page and in my boilerplate layout. I have tried moving the tags around to different places but the server-side validation is the only part working.. the form won't run the client side validation.

```
<% layout('layouts/boilerplate') %> 
<div class="row">
    <h1 class="text-center">Create Artist Profile</h1>
    <div class="col-6 offset-3">
        <form action="/artists/new" method="POST" novalidate class="validated-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div class="mb-3">
                <label class="form-label" for="email">Email</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="name@domain.com" required>
                <div class="valid-feedback">
                    Looks good!
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="mb-3">
                <label for="formFile" class="form-label">Upload band photo</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="file" id="image" name="image" multiple="false">
              </div>
                <div class="mb-3">
                    <button class="btn btn-success">Create Profile</button>
                </div>
            <a href="/artists">All artists</a>
        </form>        
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's the script tag from the body of my layouts/boilerplate.ejs

```
    <script>
        (function () {
        'use strict'

        bsCustomFileInput.init()

        // Fetch all the forms we want to apply custom Bootstrap validation styles to
        const forms = document.querySelectorAll('.validated-form')

        // Loop over them and prevent submission
        Array.from(forms)
            .forEach(function (form) {
                form.addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
                    if (!form.checkValidity()) {
                        event.preventDefault()
                        event.stopPropagation()
                    }

                    form.classList.add('was-validated')
                }, false)
            })
    })
    </script>
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong with this form?

Answer (score 1):

In order to form action to execute the button should be input | button type submit.

This is missing in your code, as far as I can see.

If your code does not work, try removing class 'validated-form' and `novalidate` attribute from:

```html
<form action="/artists/new" method="POST" novalidate class="validated-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="mb-3">
    <label class="form-label" for="email">Email</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="name@domain.com" required>
    <div class="valid-feedback">
      Looks good!
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="mb-3">
    <label for="formFile" class="form-label">Upload band photo</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="file" id="image" name="image" multiple="false">
  </div>
  <div class="mb-3">
    <button class="btn btn-success">Create Profile</button>
  </div>
  <a href="/artists">All artists</a>
</form>
```

To:

```html
<form action="/artists/new" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="mb-3">
    <label class="form-label" for="email">Email</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="name@domain.com" required>
    <div class="valid-feedback">
      Looks good!
     </div>
   </div>
   <div class="mb-3">
     <label for="formFile" class="form-label">Upload band photo</label>
     <input class="form-control" type="file" id="image" name="image" multiple="false">
   </div>
   <div class="mb-3">
     <button type='submit' class="btn btn-success">Create Profile</button>
   </div>
   <a href="/artists">All artists</a>
</form>
```

It seems to me that is the following code is not working on server side, but is working in the local host. The propagation and defaults are passing in the code therefore preventing the javascript validation.

`form.checkValidity()` function is returning true all the time:

```js
if (!form.checkValidity()) {
  event.preventDefault()
  event.stopPropagation()
}
```

After the change there is not javascript to validate the form and there will be browser end validation only that was allowed at all times, when I tried on the server end.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried changing the form class to "needs-validation"?

also try this code

```
   (function() {
    'use strict';
    window.addEventListener('load', function() {
        
var forms = document.querySelectorAll('.validated-form')
       
        var validation = Array.prototype.filter.call(forms, function(form) {
            form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
                if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    event.stopPropagation();
                }
                form.classList.add('was-validated');
            }, false);
        });
    }, false);
})();
```

Comment: No luck (that field is editable and as long as it matches with my "class" field in the form it should work). The form validation used to work when I first set it up but I must have accidentally edited something along the way and now it doesn't work any more.

Comment: I think the problem is `Array.from(forms)
            .forEach(function (form) {
                form.addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
                    if (!form.checkValidity()) {`
The way you declare the array and the foreach is ok?

Comment: I updated the code, try it and let me know if it works

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Hi @nexdanger - still no luck. I appreciate you trying. I was able to get my server side validation to work (using Joi) so I'm wondering if in creating the server side validation, I've somehow turned off the client validation. It may be a bigger issue than I've covered with the context above.